# Angular-datatable bad button rendering when responsive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I use Angular-datatable with the responsive plugin. Everything work in desktop mode.

I have 2 buttons to edit/remove users.

```
function actionHtml(data, type, full, meta) {
  $scope.users[data.id] = data;
  return '<md-button ng-click="showDialogAddUser(' + data.id + ')" class="md-raised md-primary">Edit</md-button>\
    <md-button ng-click="removeUser(' + data.id + ')" class="md-raised md-warn button-admin-user">Remove</md-button>\
  ';
}
```

[image]

When i reduce my window i have

[image]

How can i keep my  design on mobile and make the ng-click working with the datatable responsive plugin ?

Comment: So, your question is not related to the large images at all !?  Your question is that your `ng-click`'s not is working?

Comment: I have 2 questions. #1: How can i keep my "buttons" design instead of the text Edit/Remove. #2: ng-click doesn't work in mobile view. The big screen is for buttons Edit/Remove.